# Can I find all .c files, compile them and create a static library with them all at once?

Tags: c, linux, static-libraries, static-linking

I want to find all my c source files from parent directory, compile them and create a static library with them all at once. I tried this
`ar -rc libmylib.a < gcc -c < find ../ -type f -name '*.c'` but it throws:
bash: gcc: No such file or directory.

Comment: This isn’t how pipe redirection works. Anyway, what do you mean by “all at once”?

Comment: Using just a line of code i.e. not separating the codes

Comment: can you write a script that will produce a `makefile` and then call `make`?

Comment: No, I'm just starting c.

Comment: What’s the point of having a single line of code? If you want to perform only one call, put all the necessary logic into a function or a shell script file and invoke that.

Comment: A good point, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gcc` doesn't print the object file name so you'll have to divide it up into two command lines. Example:

```
find .. -type f -name '*.c' -exec gcc -c {} \;
ar -rc libmylib.a *.o
```

Comment: Why is the backslash doing?

Comment: @AbdulrazaqAS It escapes the subsequent character, to prevent the shell from interpreting it as a command separator (instead, it now gets passed as an argument to `find`, which requires it after `-exec`). You could also use quotes, `';'`, same as for the preceding glob pattern (`'*.c'` or, equivalently, `\*.c`).